# Lookup zip codes in list of ranges

Tags: java, algorithm

I've a list of zip code ranges, such that one region can multiple zip codes.

```
class Zip {

    Long rangeStart;    // zip code range first
    Long rangeEnd;      // zip code range last
    String regionName;
}
```

Input 1: `List<Zip> zipList`
Input 2: `Long zipCodeToSearch`

There are NO overlapping ranges.

I've to design a solution where when user inputs a zip code I've to lookup the `List<Zip>` and return its region name.

I've to solve it for both when the `zipList` is sorted as well as when it is unsorted.

**My solution when zipList is sorted using Binary search:**

1. Create a `HashMap<Integer, String>` storing an index & region name. e.g.

> 1 -> Hawaii
> 2 -> LA
> 3 -> NY

2. Create a list storing start and end of the range. i.e.

```
List<Long> rangeList;
for (Zip zip : zipList) {
    rangeList.add(zip.rangeStart);
    rangeList.add(zip.rangeEnd);
}
```

3. Using binary search iteratively check if `zipCodeToSearch` is within mid and its neighbor.

And by neighbor, I mean I'll check both left and right as in binary search.
If result is found return `map.get(mid/2)`

**My solution when `zipList` is unsorted:**

This is basically linear search and I'm checking like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < rangeList.size(); i += 2) {
    if (rangeList.get(i - 1) <= zipCodeToSearch && zipCodeToSearch <= rangeList.get(i)) {
        return i / 2;
    }
}
```

Are there any better solution?

Comment: I advise you to ask on CodeReview. By the way, there isn't any better solution, you are searching in O(log(n)) in the best case and in O(n) in the worst. The only thing is that you could sort the list in case you need many consequent lookups, and this could justify the initial O(n*log(n)) cost

Comment: Have you considered simply constructing a hash whose keys are zip codes and whose values are region names?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the Zip list

```
static Zip getZip(List<Zip> zipList, long range) {
    for (Zip zip: zipList)
        if (range >= zip.rangeStart && range <= zip.rangeEnd)
            return zip;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method to your `Zip` class to check if a zip code is within range:

```
class Zip {
    Long rangeStart;
    Long rangeEnd;
    String regionName;

    public boolean isInRange(long zip) {
        return zip >= rangeStart && zip <= rangeEnd;
    }
}
```

Then you can `stream` and filter the `zipList` to get the region name:

```
public static String findRegionName(List<Zip> zipList, long searchZip) {
    return zipList.stream().filter(zip -> zip.isInRange(searchZip))
            .map(Zip::getRegionName).findAny().orElse(null);
}
```